# Why may this construction be not working?

Tags: python-3.x

I receive, that first iteration 1 is not a number.

```
 numbers = ['1', 'apple', '2', '3', '4', '5']

 print ('Your numbers are...')
 for f in numbers:
     if f.isalpha():
         print ('This is not a number!') # (It actually isn't.)
         break
     print (f)
 else:
     print ('Here are your numbers!')
```

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: Are you sure that's what's happening? `'apple'` is not a number.

Comment: I receive, that first iteration 1 is not a number. Though I want to receive that apple is not a number

Comment: The construction should print 'Here are your numbers!' if list contains numbers only, and 'This is not a number!' and value of f, if list contains not-number at f iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing this...

```
Your numbers are...
```

Then you hit the **first** iteration, `f = '1'` and `print (f)`:

```
1
```

Then you get to the **second** iteration, `f = 'apple'` and `print ('This is not a number!')`...

```
This is not a number!
```

This is to be expected.

Your output would be clearer with this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


numbers = ['1', 'apple', '2', '3', '4', '5']

print ('Your numbers are...')
for f in numbers:
    if f.isalpha():
        print('{} is not a number!'.format(f))
        break
else:
    print('Here are your numbers: {}'.format(numbers))
```

Comment: @user2742080 as this answer resolves your question, please accept the answer